# Ember.js dynamic components

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, htmlbars

I have two Models `Admin` and `User`
My application template is as follow

```
//application.hbs
{{outlet}}
{{header-nav}}
```

What I want to do (if it is possible) to make `{{header-nav}}` customizable, I explain : 
If the `admin` authenticate I want to render the component `{{admin-header}}`
in the case the `user` authenticate it should render `{{user-header}}`.
How can I build what to render in `application.hbs` dynamically ?

Answer (score 3):

You could define `isAdmin` computed property in Application Controller:

```
// application controller 
isAdmin: Ember.computed(function() {
  // your logic here
})

// application template
{{#if isAdmin}}
  {{admin-header}}
{{else}}
  {{user-admin}}
{{/if}}
```

or you could wrap it as `header-nav` component with `isAdmin` property, so:

```
// application template
{{header-nav isAdmin=isAdmin}}
```

UPDATE 
(Details with ember-simple-auth for @Grimmy)

1) Inject `currentUser` into `session` (for example, https://stackoverflow.com/a/30894082/4950029)

2) Resolve `currentUser` in `beforeModel` hook and set `currentUser` controller property:

```
//route
beforeModel: function() {
  var self = this;
  this.session.get('currentUser').then(function(user) {
    self.controllerFor( self.routeName ).set('currentUser', user);
  },function() {
    self.controllerFor( self.routeName ).set('currentUser', null);
  });
}

//controller
isAdmin: Ember.computed('currentUser.role', function() {
  return (this.get('currentUser.role') === 'admin');
}),

//template
{{#if isAdmin}}
  {{admin-header}}
{{else}}
  {{user-admin}}
{{/if}}
```

or as answered above

```
//controller
roleBasedComponentName: Ember.computed('currentUser.role', function() {
  return ((this.get('currentUser.role') === 'admin') ? 'admin-header' : 'user-header');
})

//template
{{component roleBasedComponentName user=currentUser}}
```

Comment: Can you give me a full example of the controller please ?

Comment: You'd like to see something special?

Comment: Using ember-simple-auth to authenticate, I want to get the current user.role to decide which view to render

Comment: In route, what does the "nil" mean please ?

Comment: I'm using ember-simple-auth  0.7.3, I tried your solution I got this error : "Error while processing route: index" "this.session.get(...) is undefined" "beforeModel@http://localhost:4200/, any idea ? (sorry to bother you again)

Comment: Looks like `this.session` is null. You probably don't include the `ApplicationRouteMixin` or `AuthenticatedRouteMixin` properly or something else. See https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth#the-session how to use session in routes. And why not '0.8.0' version?

Comment: I built my app with ember-simple-auth 0.7.3 when I tried the 0.8.0 beta 2, I've got some issues, I got nothing when I try to show for example {{session.user.lastName}}  in my templates

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82817/discussion-between-artych-and-grimmy).

Answer (score 3):

You may use `{{component}}` helper, but you need to have component name determined first, so, in your controller:

```
nameForComponent: Ember.computed('user.isAdmin', function()  {
// if admin return admin-header else user-header
})
```

Then, in your template:

```
{{component nameForComponent}}
```

It was designed and introduced short time ago for such use cases.

You can also go more fancy:

```
{{component (if user.isAdmin 'admin-header' 'user-header') }}
```

Comment: SO sorry of my late rely, i Thank you for your answer, nameForComponent in which controller should I define it please (I am new to Ember )

Comment: In application controller or headernav component, depends  in which template you use component helper.

Comment: Ok, can you please give me an example of what should return nameForComponent, knowing that I am using Ember-simple-auth for authentication and in my user I have a role attribute which it can take either  "admin" or "user"

Comment: `nameForComponent` should return component name - string `admin-header` or `user-header`.

Comment: One last question, what would be the best approach to get the current user (role) using ember-simple-auth

Comment: I have not used this addon.