# Ember Simple Auth - injecting current user into every route

Tags: ember.js, dependency-injection, ember-simple-auth

I am building a site using Ember Simple Auth.

I followed [these instructions](http://blog.willrax.com/fetching-the-current-user-with-simple-auth/) to try and add the current user object to the session and it worked, using this slightly adapted code:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import Session from 'simple-auth/session';

export default {
  name: "current-user",
  before: "simple-auth",
  initialize: function(container) {
    Session.reopen({
      setCurrentUser: function() {
        var accessToken = this.get('secure.token');
        var _this = this;
        if (!Ember.isEmpty(accessToken)) {
          return container.lookup('store:main').find('user', 'me').then(function(user) {
            _this.set('content.currentUser', user);
          });
        }
      }.observes('secure.token'),
      setAccount: function() {
        var _this = this;
        return container.lookup('store:main').find('account', this.get('content.currentUser.account.content.id')).then(function(account) {
          _this.set('content.account', account);
        });
      }.observes('content.currentUser'),
    });
  }
};
```

However, using the latest version of Ember I'm getting the following:

> DEPRECATION: `lookup` was called on a Registry. The `initializer` API no longer receives a container, and you should use an `instanceInitializer` to look up objects from the container. See http://emberjs.com/guides/deprecations#toc_deprecate-access-to-instances-in-initializers for more details.

I know that I need to split the above into /app/initializers and /app/instance-initializers (as per the notes [here](http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_deprecate-access-to-instances-in-initializers)) but I'm not quite sure how to go about it.

Of course, if there is an easier/cleaner way to make the user and account objects available to every route/template I'd love to hear them :)

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works for me on:

- ember-cli: 0.2.7 (ember: 1.12.0, ember-data: 1.0.0-beta.18)
- ember-cli-simple-auth: 0.8.0-beta.3

**Note:**

- ember-data: 1.13. Store is registered in an initializer, should work as is
- ember-data: 1.0.0-beta.19. Store is registered in an instance-initializer, some adjustments needed

1) Customize session

```
//config/environment.js
ENV['simple-auth'] = {
  session: 'session:custom',
  ...
}

//app/sessions/custom.js
import Session from 'simple-auth/session';

export default Session.extend({

  // here _store is ember-data store injected by initializer
  // why "_store"? because "store" is already used by simple-auth as localStorage
  // why initializer? I tried 
  // _store: Ember.inject.service('store') and got error

  currentUser: function() {
    var userId = this.get('secure.userId');
    if (userId && this.get('isAuthenticated')) {
      return this._store.find('user', userId);
    }
  }.property('secure.userId', 'isAuthenticated')

});
```

2) Inject store to session by initializer (otherwise find() wouldn't work)

```
//app/initializers/session-store
export function initialize(container, application) {
  application.inject('session:custom', '_store', 'store:main')

  // "store:main" is highly dynamic depepeding on ember-data version
  // in 1.0.0-beta.19 (June 5, 2015) => "store:application"
  // in 1.13 (June 16, 2015) => "service:store"
}

export default {
  name: 'session-store',
  after: 'ember-data',
  initialize: initialize
}
```

3) In template

```
{{#if session.isAuthenticated}}
  {{session.currentUser.name}}
{{/if}}
```

Note: this does not relieve you from deprecations generated by `ember-simple-auth` itself.

Comment: A fantastic answer, thank you very much. 

I had to update my custom Devise::SessionsController to return userId along with token and email, but other than that it worked flawlessly.

Comment: Artych, just a quick follow-up question - I am able to access the session objects in controllers using `this.get('session.currentUser')` but this doesn't seem to work in routes. Should I be doing something differently? Thanks

Comment: Don't forget that `currentUser` is a promise.       `this.get('session.currentUser').then(function(user) {
     console.log('user-name', user.get('name'))
});` works in every route. (And thank you for previous comment)

Comment: You can also leave out the initializer by adding: `var _store = this.container.lookup('store:application');` to custom.js. This also helps if your _store-variable is undefined (error: "find on undefined").

Comment: Tried this on `Ember: 2.2.0`, `Ember Data: 2.2.1` and `Ember Simple Auth: 1.0.0` and didn't work.

Answer (score 6):

First of all you shouldn't reopen the session but use a custom session instead (see this example: https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/master/examples/4-authenticated-account.html#L132). Also you you shouldn't only load the current user when the access token is set but when the session is authenticated (`'session.get('isAuthenticated')'`) which makes your code not dependent on the authenticator.

The deprecation warnings regarding the use of the registry in the initializer will go away in ESA 0.9.0 hopefully.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, marcoow, and for all your work on ember-simple-auth

Comment: Hi @marcoow can you please update the link? Or provide a new example?

Comment: The whole concept of custom sessions doesn't exist anymore since 1.0. Instead you can just use a service - see the dummy app in the repo: https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/tree/master/tests/dummy/app/services

Comment: For anyone else looking at @marcoow's link, you may want this also to see the use of the service: https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/master/tests/dummy/app/routes/application.js

Answer (score 2):

Here's a before and after of an initializer/instance-initializer that I did the other day.

#### Before

```
export function initialize( container, application ) {
    var session = Ember.Object.create({
        user:null,
        authorization:null
    });

    application.register('session:main', session, { instantiate: false });
    application.inject('route', 'session', 'session:main');
    application.inject('controller', 'session', 'session:main');
    application.inject('adapter', 'session', 'session:main');
}
```

#### After

```
export function initialize( instance) {
    var session = Ember.Object.create({
        user:null,
        authorization:null
    });

    instance.registry.register('session:main', session, { instantiate: false });
    instance.registry.injection('route', 'session', 'session:main');
    instance.registry.injection('controller', 'session', 'session:main');
    instance.registry.injection('adapter', 'session', 'session:main');
}
```

#### Ember Data Stuff

Ember Data in the latest iterations should be fetched using `store:application`

```
export function initialize(instance) {
    var store = instance.container.lookup('store:application');
    ....
}

export default {
    name: 'socket',
    initialize: initialize,
    after:['ember-data']
};
```