# Ember Simple Auth - setting multiple properties in a custom session

Tags: ember.js, promise, ember-simple-auth

Following on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30872684/ember-simple-auth-injecting-current-user-into-every-route/30894082#30894082) I am trying to set both the currentUser and the account properties in my custom session:

```
/app/sessions/custom.js

import Ember from 'ember';
import Session from 'simple-auth/session';

export default Session.extend({
  currentUser: Ember.computed('secure.user_id', 'isAuthenticated', function() {
    console.log('currentUser');
    var userId = this.get('secure.user_id');
    if (userId && this.get('isAuthenticated')) {
      return this._store.find('user', userId);
    }
  }),
  account: Ember.computed('currentUser', function() {
    console.log('account');
    this.get('currentUser').then(function(currentUser) {
      return this._store.find('account', currentUser.get('account').id);
    })
  })
});
```

but for some reason the `console.log('account');` is never called. I guess that this is because currentUser is a promise and thus hasn't yet resolved?

Should I return an Ember.RSVP.hash instead?

Comment: Have you tried using a `DS.PromiseObject`?

Comment: i think if you try `Ember.computed('secure.user_id', ..)` instead `Ember.computed('currentUser', ...)` it will work

Comment: and you could try promise:
`account: Ember.computed('secure.user_id', function() { return this.get('currentUser').get('account') });` this is simpler

Comment: or `account: Ember.computed('secure.user_id', function() { 
  return this.get('currentUser').then(function(user) { 
    return user.get('account');
  });
})` if comments above do not work

Comment: Okay I am missing something here! In the above, currentUser outputs the `console.log('currentUser')` correctly. However, if I change it to anything other than currentUser (or add other functions) it doesn't work. This is EVEN if the only thing in the function is `console.log`. I've tried logging but it still only works if called currentUser... >_<